# Allow my customer to configure their own domain to the same application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I'm building a shopify-like application. right now when a customer creates a store, he gets some subdomain like `https://customer1.shopify-like.com`

My Shopify-like frontend application hosts on AWS/ec2 and built with react.js. So, when you visit `customer1.shopify-like.com` my Nginx(ec2) configuration catches all `*.shopify-like.com` and load the same react-application (proxy_pass to `http://frontend:80`, all services up by `docker-compose`).

and it works fine.

the question is how to allow my customer to configure their own domain as Shopify does.
[docs link][1]

> Set up your existing domain to connect to Shopify If you've purchased
> your domain through a third party, then you need to edit the following
> DNS settings:
>
> Your A record should point to Shopify's IP address, which is
> 23.227.38.65 Copy
>
> Your www CNAME record should point to shops.myshopify.com Copy.

1. why Shopify asks you to set CNAME to `shops.myshopify.com`? what's the proposal?
2. should I ask my customer to configure `CNAME` to `customer1.shopify-like.com` and `A Record` to my ec2 IP?
3. if yes, why? because if they just configure the `A Record` to my ec2 IP. could I catch all requests with Nginx and proxy_pass to my frontend app?
   [1]: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/connecting-domains